# Azure pipeline re run task if fails

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I hope somebody can help me to understand the best approach to solve this is which is related to azure pipeline.

I have an azure pipeline, yaml file that run a selenium script. The script runs just fine, but due to the agent limitations, this selenium script once a day fails returning a false positive. My yaml file looks like this:

```
schedules:
  - cron: '5 */1 * * *'
    displayName: Daily Trigger
    branches:
      include:
        - BYOD
    always: true

variables:
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

jobs:
  - job: Main
    steps:
      - task: UsePythonVersion@0
        inputs:
          versionSpec: '3.x'
          addToPath: true
      - script: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          status=$?
          if [ $status -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "##[section]Upgraded pip..."
          else
            python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          fi

          pip install selenium

          status=$?
          if [ $status -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "##[section]Installed sellenium..."
          else
            pip install selenium
          fi

      - task: Pythonscript@0
        continueOnError: true
        inputs:
          scriptSource: 'filePath'
          scriptPath: './script1.py'
      - task: Pythonscript@0
        condition: failed()
        inputs:
          scriptSource: 'filePath'
          scriptPath: './script1.py'
```

The script triggers once every hours..sometimes it doesn't fail for days but eventually  will fails because it doesn't find an element, but this error is due to the agent that probably is too slow to load the content.

So my idea was to make the pipeline to re-run 1 more time if the first time fails, I believe this should eventually solve the issue.

Checking in azure DevOps portal, there is the option to `rerun failed task` but I couldn't find anything in azure yaml documentation.

One of the solution I found, is to duplicate the job, and make use of `condition`.

Can anyone enlighten if there is any better option to solve this issue please?

Thank you very much for your time and help.

EDIT:
I did try the above solution. The output is as I expected to be in event of a failure, as you can see:

[image]

The fist python script fails, which triggers the second and succeeds, but the overall pipeline return a fail. Is there an option how can I make the pipeline succeed if one of the 2 tasks succeeds? because the task are identical and means that my script is working

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box solution for providing retry in case of failure. If you want to retry last step, yes you need to repeat last step again and add condition:

```yaml
schedules:
  - cron: '5 */1 * * *'
    displayName: Daily Trigger
    branches:
      include:
        - master
    always: true
trigger: none
variables:
  vmImageName: "ubuntu-latest"

steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: "3.x"
      addToPath: true
  - script: |
      python -m pip install --upgrade pip
      pip install selenium
  - task: Pythonscript@0
    continueOnError: true
    inputs:
      scriptSource: "filePath"
      scriptPath: "./script.py"
  - task: Pythonscript@0
    condition: eq(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'SucceededWithIssues')
    inputs:
      scriptSource: "filePath"
      scriptPath: "./script.py"
```

If you are worried about this part:

```
  - script: |
      python -m pip install --upgrade pip
      pip install selenium
```

you can check last result and repeat if needed:

```yaml
  - script: |
      python -m pip install --upgrade pip

      status=$?
      if [ $status -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "##[section]Upgraded pip..."
      else
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
      fi

      pip install selenium

      status=$?
      if [ $status -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "##[section]Installed sellenium..."
      else
        pip install selenium
      fi
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you useful answer, as usual. I did update my pipeline code updated. The difference we have, is that your code is cleaner and will run the script portion only if something goes wrong at that stage, while in mine will run all the job together. I will try this configuration and if it works, I will update with your solution to save some time during the runtime.

Comment: Hi, I did update my OP with the pipeline output. if one of the task fails, the overall pipeline fails, I was wondering how can I make it succeeds if on of the 2 task succeeds? Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Please add `continueOnError: true` on task which tends to fail. It will mark then job as partially succeded.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I added `continueOnError: true` to the first task, but there is a weird output. If that task fails, the second doesn't trigger and the overall task return a Warning.

Comment: Please update your question with changes in YAML.

Comment: I updated the yaml script In my OP. Thank you very much

Comment: Ok pelase change condition from `failed()` to `eq(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'SucceededWithIssues')`

Comment: Now is triggering the second task if the first fails, but I am still getting the warning icon in this scenario. I guess is not possible to mark it sone succeeded if the second task succeds right?